# How can I fix the Groupby function problems in python with the key error?

Tags: python, dataframe

I try to pivot my dataframe by using Groupby function in python. When I read my data from google drive as a set of pandas dataframe and groupby the column's name "Brance Code" that is a one of column names. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPDL8.jpg)

How ever the error message show me that "KeyError: 'Brance Code'".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF14A.jpg)

What is my mistake and How can I fix it ?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Could you please add some data, so people can recreate your issue and try to fix it?

Comment: Paste your code, not images of it please

Answer (score 1):

try the following way

```
unpivoted = df.groupby(['Brance Code'])['Count of PLANTNUMBER'].sum()
```